# Android Library thread safe

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've a small android library which handles a serial port, it has basic functionality like open, read, write and close.

I have made an applications that uses this library to write on the serial port and read the responses, within this application there is a thread that periodically opens the serial port asks for the status get the response and close the serial port.

I want to protect the serial communication in a way that if the main thread opens the communication the secondary thread that only checks the status can not open it and wait for the main thread to finish.

```
 class SerialChannel extends Channel
    {
        private SerialPortUtility serialPortUtility;
        private static final String SERIAL_FILE     = "/dev/ttyMT2";
        private static final String CONTROL_FILE    = "/sys/devices/platform/file";
        private static final String UNKNOWN_COMMAND = "UNKNOWN COMMAND";
        private FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
        private FileInputStream fileInputStream;

        @Override
        public void open() throws CommunicationException
        {

            try
            {
                if (isSerialOpened() != SerialStatus.Open)
                {
                    toggleSerial(SerialStatus.Open.getStatus());
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }

                serialPortUtility   = getSerialPortUtility();
                fileInputStream     = (FileInputStream) serialPortUtility.getInputStream();
                fileOutputStream    = (FileOutputStream) serialPortUtility.getOutputStream();
                currentProcess      = Optional.of(Thread.currentThread().getId());

                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
            {
                throw new CommunicationException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws CommunicationException
        {


            if (serialPortUtility == null)
            {
                throw new CommunicationException("SerialPort is null");
            }

            try
            {
                toggleSerial(SerialStatus.Close.getStatus());
                fileOutputStream.close();
                fileInputStream.close();
                serialPortUtility.close();

                fileInputStream     = null;
                fileOutputStream    = null;
                serialPortUtility   = null;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new CommunicationException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void send(byte[] buffer, int timeout, int length) throws CommunicationException
        {
            if (fileOutputStream == null)
            {
                throw new CommunicationException("Problem while sending data!");
            }

            try
            {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer);
                fileOutputStream.flush();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new CommunicationException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] receive(int length, int timeout) throws CommunicationException
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] buffer               = new byte[length];
            int ret;
            int totalSize               = 0;

            if (fileInputStream == null)
            {
                throw new CommunicationException("FileInputStream is null!");
            }

            try
            {

                long millisStart = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                boolean timeoutReached;

                while (true)
                {
                    timeoutReached = (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - millisStart > timeout * 1000);

                    if (fileInputStream.available() <= 0 && timeoutReached)
                    {
                        expectingResult = false;
                        throw new CommunicationException("Error");
                    }
                    else if (fileInputStream.available() > 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                millisStart = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

                while (totalSize != length && (ret = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    String received = new String(buffer);

                    stringBuilder.append(received);

                    if(buffer.length == 15 && received.equals(UNKNOWN_COMMAND))
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    totalSize += ret;
                }

                expectingResult = false;

            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new CommunicationException(e.getMessage());
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString().getBytes();
        }

        private SerialPortUtility getSerialPortUtility() throws IOException
        {
            if (serialPortUtility == null)
            {
                File file = new File(SERIAL_FILE);
                int baudRate = 115200;

                return new SerialPortUtility(file, baudRate, 0);
            }

            return serialPortUtility;
        }

        private void toggleSerial(String data) throws IOException
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(CONTROL_FILE));
            fos.write(data.getBytes());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }

        private SerialStatus isSerialOpened() throws IOException
        {
            byte[] buffer       = new byte[1];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(CONTROL_FILE));
            int result          = fis.read(buffer);
            fis.close();

            if (result > -1 && buffer[0] == 1)
            {
                return SerialStatus.Open;
            }

            return SerialStatus.Close;
        }


}
```

This class extends custom class Channel that implements an interface with the methods open, close, read, send and implements also AutoCloseable.

Now if I make the open method synchronized any thread that enters here will lock, but will lock until it exits the open method, and when the thread moves to the another method let's say read and stay there until it gets a response, the checker thread will come and enters the open method. Using AutoCloseable the close method will execute and close the serial port communication. If I synchronize an object, there still is a window when the object is not synchronized.

How can I tell the checker thread that the communication is already opened and make him wait until the main thread finish.

Checker looks like this, it is within an timer:

```
try(Channel ch = CommunicationFactory.getInstance().selectChannel(CommunicationType.SERIAL))
{
     ch.open();
     //do stuff
}
catch (CommunicationException ex)
{
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The "main" thread looks the same only that it is in an AysncTask.

If additional informations are required please let me know!

Thank you in advance for your effort and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tell the checker thread that the communication is already opened and make him wait until the main thread finish.

I don't fully understand your code but the critical thing with threads and locking is to make sure that all threads are calling code that is `synchronized` on the *same* object instance.

> If I synchronize an object, there still is a window when the object is not synchronized.

Not if you use the same instance of the object.  Making each of the `public` methods in `SerialChannel` `synchronized` will make sure that only 1 thread can be using the object at once.

I suspect that your real problem is not about protecting the `SerialChannel` object but more about race-conditions between the threads.  They need to make multiple calls to the methods and they can block each other or interleave in an improper manner.

You can get around this with a couple of changes.  You can make the `send(...)` and `receive(...)` methods auto-opening.  Threads would just call `send()` or `receive()` which in turn would internally call `open()` if the `fileInputStream` or `fileOutputStream` was `null`.  The thread would be inside of a `synchronized` so this would not be interrupted by another thread.

Another completely different model to consider would be to have one thread reading from the serial port and another writing to it that are dedicated to that task -- they would be built into the `SerialChannel` object.   They would share data with the external threads using a read `BlockingQueue` and a write `BlockingQueue`.  Then the serial port is opened early in your application which starts the IO threads and the external threads never worry about the IO.  They just `put()` and `take()` from the queues.  I typically do this (for example) when reading and writing to the console.

Hope something here helps.

Comment: Thank you Gary for the response, you pointed out very good, the real problem is "race-conditions between the threads". I will take in consideration your suggestions.